# es6 import index.js by directory name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, import, es6-modules

I've been looking around and can't seem to find a clear answer on this.

Is it possible to import an index.js file from a client directory using the directory name (omitting `/index.js`)? If so, how? This is a new project and I don't really want to bundle my code at this point.

The node version is v17.1.0.

**File structure**

```
package.json
server.js
src/
  index.js
  utils/
    index.js
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --ignore src"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```js
import express from 'express'

express()
  .use(express.static('src'))
  .get('/', (_, res) => res.send(`
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>`))
  .listen(3000, () => console.log(`Running at http://localhost:3000`))
```

**src/index.js**

```js
import { stuff } from './utils'

// Firefox: Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/utils/” 
// was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

I've tried running the app with `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js` and tried adding `express.static.mime.define({'text/javascript': ['js']})` to server.js, but neither worked for me.

Comment: Every `js` acts as a module and without importing that module won't be able to export  it.  One way could be to create a new file and import all the files in it and export from there. However, it might create circular dependency.

Comment: Actually that's what I'm using /utils/index.js for: To export other files in the utils/ directory.